# Can I use a Swift extension to implement a custom getter for an Objective-C class' property?

Tags: swift

Say I have an Objective-C class with a public property called `foo`, and I want to give it a custom getter. Can I do this in Swift with an extension of the class?

Comment: Yes, unsuccessfully, which is why I'm here. Just using the var and a get block causes a "using variable within its own context" bug.

Comment: So you are redeclaring the `var`? That also does not work in pure Swift

Comment: So I've seen, curious if there's something that may. :)